# Eliminar saltos de línea de un txt con PHP

Tags: php

estoy intentando quitar líneas de un TXT con PHP

El tema es simple, tengo un txt con los números del 1 al 5:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Luego de esto, quiero buscar el número 2 y quitarlo, para ello utilizo `str_replace()`

```
$n = "2";
$content = file_get_contents($archivo);
$content = str_replace($n, '', $content);
```

Posteriormente con el uso de file_get_contents, sobre-escribo el archivo e inserto el contenido, pero este queda con el salto de línea en donde estaba el número 2.

```
$txt = fopen($faltantes, "w+");
file_put_contents($faltantes, $content);
fclose($txt);

//Output:
1

3
4
5
```

Lo que no logro hacer, es quitar ese salto de línea, he usado la búsqueda de `"\n"` y hasta `PHP_EOL`, pero no me ha resultado, puede que esto solo sea problema de lógica.

Comment: Sera que esto pueda ayudarte en lo que buscas? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string

Comment: No, actualmente @Trauma me dijo que usara esos, pero no funcionaron, el mismo borró sus comentarios. No se logró concatenar el número con el salto de línea. (y es el mismo post XD)

Comment: No es necesario abrir el archivo para usar file_put_contents

Comment: Ah no, ese es código que me sobró de otros intentos XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al momento de reemplazar debes incluir el salto de linea.
Si es windows sería \r\n (CRLF)
Si es *NIX sería \n (LF)

[`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) puede usar un array como primer parametro. En el colocas todas las posibilidades de reemplazo.
En tu caso serían estos dos arriba mencionados. La tercera opción es por si haya quedado suelto algún \r.
El **orden** de los elementos del array es importante.

```
$n = "2";
$arr = array("$n\r\n", "$n\n", "$n\r");

$content = file_get_contents($archivo);
$content = str_replace($arr, '', $content);

file_put_contents($archivo, $content);
```

Comment: ESO era lo que nos faltaba, concatenar correctamente el valor con el salto de línea. Duda, esto funcionaría ya sea en windows y unix cierto ?

Comment: Esa es la idea con los tres patrones. Patrones mas complejos o presencia de espacios en blanco al inicio o final de la linea ya ameritan expresiones regulares.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ;)